# Sort out all messages that have 'unread = true'

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Hi i need to sort out messages that are not read in Gmail. But i can't pull out the body, sender and attachments properties when im adding the 'isUnread'.

```
 var firstThread = GmailApp.getInboxThreads(0,1)[0];
 var unread = firstThread.isUnread();
 var message = unread.getMessages()[0];
```

If i do it like this it works, but i do not get the unread messages.

```
var firstThread = GmailApp.getInboxThreads(0,1)[0];
   var message = firstThread.getMessages()[0];
```

Any tips?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe is just a matter of order, you can try

```
var firstThread = GmailApp.getInboxThreads(0,1)[0];
 var messages = firstThread.getMessages();
 var unread = [];
 for (var i=0; i<messages.length; i++){
  if (messages[i].isUnread()) unread.push(messages[i]);
 }
```

Comment: What is the .push for? Never seen that before. 
And it did not work, same error it can't pull out the properties from "messages"

Comment: `.push` adds an element at the end of an array.
I'll have a look at google api and see what can I do

Comment: I can't pull out properties from "GmailApp.search('label:unread');"

Comment: I can't pull out properties from the variable "unread". It's just empty.

Comment: `var firstThread = GmailApp.getInboxThreads(0,1)[0];
var messages = [];`
Check if thread has unread messages and copy messages
`if (firstThread.isUnread()) messages = firstThread.getMessages();`
retrieve unread messages
`var umessages=[]
for (var i=0; i<messages.length; i++){
 if (messages[i].isUnread()) umessages.push(messages[i]);
}`

I tried this and it works. I end up with var `umessages` with all the unread.
It is possible that you don't have any unread?

Answer (score 0):

sailens approach works as expected, search is also an easy way to get what you want. 
Below 2 small functions to demonstrate:

```
function getUnreadMessages() {
 var unreadThreads = GmailApp.getInboxThreads(0,100);
  if(unreadThreads.length==0){Logger.log('no unread messages');return};
  var unreads = [];unreads.push('\n\n');
  for(var n in unreadThreads){
    if(unreadThreads[n].isUnread()){unreads.push(unreadThreads[n].getFirstMessageSubject()+' has '+unreadThreads[n].getMessageCount()+' message(s)\n')};
  }

  Logger.log(unreads);//shows the unread threads with their subjects and number of messages
}


function searchUnreads() {
  var unreadThreads = GmailApp.search('label:unread');
  if(unreadThreads.length==0){Logger.log('no unread messages');return};
  var unreads = [];unreads.push('\n\n');
  for(var n in unreadThreads){
    unreads.push(unreadThreads[n].getFirstMessageSubject()+' has '+unreadThreads[n].getMessageCount()+' message(s)\n');
  }
  Logger.log(unreads);//shows the unread threads with their subjects and number of messages
}
```

---

UPDATE :
a version that gets some details from every message in the threads, build in another function for ease of use

```
function getUnreadMessages() {
 var unreadThreads = GmailApp.getInboxThreads(0,100);
  if(unreadThreads.length==0){Logger.log('no unread messages');return};
  var unreads = [];unreads.push('\n\n');
  for(var n in unreadThreads){
    if(unreadThreads[n].isUnread()){unreads.push(unreadThreads[n].getFirstMessageSubject()+' has '+unreadThreads[n].getMessages()[n].getDate()
                                                 .getMessageCount()+' message(s)\n');getDetails(unreadThreads[n])};
  }

  Logger.log(unreads);//shows the unread threads with their subjects and number of messages
}


function searchUnreads() {
  var unreadThreads = GmailApp.search('label:unread');
  if(unreadThreads.length==0){Logger.log('no unread messages');return};
  var unreads = [];unreads.push('\n\n');
  for(var n in unreadThreads){
    unreads.push(unreadThreads[n].getFirstMessageSubject()+' has '+unreadThreads[n].getMessageCount()+' message(s)\n');
  }
  Logger.log(unreads);//shows the unread threads with their subjects and number of messages
}
function getDetails(thread){
  for(var n=0;n<thread.getMessageCount();n++){
    Logger.log(thread[n].getMessages()[n].getBody()+' on '+thread[n].getMessages()[n].getDate())
    Logger.log(thread[n].getMessages()[n].getAttachments());
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Serge, thanks for the help, but i dont seem to be able to pull out "getFrom();" & "getSubject();" from the variable "unreads" :(

Comment: unreads is a thread, not a message... see updated code to get details from each message

Comment: Im feeling a bit confused, all i need is 1. Get the first thread 2. Get the message of that thread in a variable 3. Extract "getFrom();" & "getSubject();" from that variable

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work and simple as it could be:

```
function myFunction() {

  var firstThread = GmailApp.getInboxThreads(0,1)[0];
 var message = firstThread.getMessages()[0];
  var unread = message.isUnread();


  var sender = message.getFrom();
  var body = "Detta mail är ursprungligen skickat från" + " " + sender + '\n' + message.getBody();
  var subject = message.getSubject();
  var attachment = message.getAttachments();
    if (unread == true){

    GmailApp.sendEmail("user.name@compay.com", subject, "",  {htmlBody: body, attachments: attachment});
  }
```